# MobileFirst - Invalid Security Check push.mobileclient

Tags: apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am getting the below error while trying to subscribe to *push notification*.

In ios version security scope has been added for push.mobileclient.

`/api/preauth/v1/preauthorize] failure. state: 400, response: Invalid Security Check push.mobileclient
2018-06-08 00:02:21.162970-0400 MetLifeContigo[71791:617087] {"responseHeaders":{"Date":"Fri, 08 Jun 2018 04:02:58 GMT","Transfer-Encoding":"Identity","Content-Language":"en-US","Content-Type":"application/json","X-Powered-By":"Servlet/3.0","Connection":"close"},"status":400,"responseText":"{\"errorCode\":\"SECURITY_CHECK_NOT_FOUND\",\"errorMsg\":\"Invalid Security Check push.mobileclient\"}","responseJSON":{"errorCode":"SECURITY_CHECK_NOT_FOUND","errorMsg":"Invalid Security Check push.mobileclient"},"errorCode":"SECURITY_CHECK_NOT_FOUND","errorMsg":"Invalid Security Check push.mobileclient"}`

Comment: This is new. Do you see it with all applications? What if you remove the scope and add it once more?

Comment: Are you possibly trying to login to "push.mobileclient" . I see the /preauthorize step failing and then it says "Invalid Security Check push.mobileclient"

Comment: Can you share your app code that results in this error ?  push.mobileclient is a scope that can be mapped to a security check. In your case, the error says that the security check was not found - it should have been the scope instead.

See this section for information on how to configure https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/ru/foundation/8.0/notifications/sending-notifications/#scope-mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m mirroring Srik's comment as an answer so this question can be accepted and closed.

Map the `push.mobileclient` scope element to the application.

1. Load the MobileFirst Operations Console and navigate to [your application] → Security → Scope-Elements Mapping, click on New.
2. Write “`push.mobileclient`” in the Scope element field. Then, click Add.

For more details check here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/ru/foundation/8.0/notifications/sending-notifications/#scope-mapping